# Why this strange infinite loop occurs

Tags: php, foreach, infinite-loop

Does anybody know why the following code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $new => $new_val) {
    foreach ($info as $old => $old_val) {
        if ($new == $old || $new_val !== $old_val) {
            $change_log[$old] = array("old" => $old_val, "new" => $new_val,);
            var_dump($change_log);
        }
    }
}
```

hangs the os (like going in the infinite loop).
But when in the "if" condition the operator || is changed to && like this:

```
if ($new == $old && $new_val !== $old_val)
```

all goes ok.
What is wrong with the || in this code?

Comment: Can you post examples of `$_POST` & `$info` ?

Comment: It's not infinite, but probably just really long. How many items are in `$_POST` and `$info`?

Comment: Could you also post the var_dump of $change_log ? Try to check how cpu is used when the program is running ?

Comment: in posts and info there are less than 50 items. Thus they are not big, and I was waiting for the system to "unhang" for about 10 mins.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the two lines of code in your if statement and change the operator back to `||`? If we can assume that less matches are going to be made with the `&&` operator as opposed to the `||` operator... then I would assume that the number of times it's updating the array and `var_dump`ing that variable is what's hanging your server and not the `||` operator.

Comment: You could replace second loop with: array_key_exist check: array_key_exist($new, $info)

Answer (score 0):

It's `var_dump($change_log);` which takes a long time. If all the values are changed, then that line executes 50 * 50 times and every time (for every mismatch) length of `$change_log` increases.

So in the worst case, it becomes 2500 times printing `$change_log` length of which might be 2500.

Put this line `var_dump($change_log);` after of the outer loop and see what happens.

Comment: You could mention in your answer that using or (||) operator does not make any sense - statement inside if clause is true with almost any input

Comment: @SamiKorhonen: I saw your comment had already addressed that :-)